# Redirect to another site using a registered domain. Godaddy

Tags: domains, redirects

I have a domain registered on godaddy (example.com).

I would like when I type daniloaraujosilva.com/blog, for example, it redirects to my blog (example.blogspot.com).

How can I perform this?

Obs.: I think this is has a relation with CNAME or A, but I don't know exactly. I am a little new at this.

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to redirect the /blog subdirectory then I wouldn't bother messing with domain name records at all, I would go for a simple 301 redirect. This will allow you to use the daniloaraujosilva.com domain for other content and only forward the /blog directory to your blogspot domain. An easy way to accomplish this would be to create a PHP file named index.php and place it inside your /blog directory:

```
<?php
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    Header( "Location: http://sapiensgarou.blogspot.com" ); 
?>
```

From an SEO standpoint this will forward all traffic properly from your domain name to your blogspot url. I am assuming that you have a hosting account connected to your GoDaddy domain and the ability to create a PHP file, if not then a different method will need to be used.